# Ayuda con algoritmo en Pseint

Tags: pseint

Necesito realizar este ejercicio en Pseint.

Se tiene una matriz de tamaño 2 * 10, que representa las 2 calificaciones (materias) de 10 estudiantes. desarrollar un algoritmo que halle e imprima:

1. Calificación promedio de los ganadores
2. Total estudiantes que deben habilitar la materia 1
3. Total estudiantes que deben habilitar las 2 materias
4. El promedio de cada estudiante y llenar un vector con los promedios
5. Total de estudiantes que ganaron todas las materias

Necesito específicamente ayuda con el punto 3, que aún no he podido programarlo.

Gracias

En el momento este es el código que tiene

```
Algoritmo Promedio2materias

    a<-2;
    Dimension mt[2,2], mtpro[1,1],vec(a),mg[2,2]
    Definir i,j Como Entero;
    promedio<-0;
    sumaganadores<-0;
    contadorganaron<-0;
    //sumahabilitanmat1<-0;
    habilitanmat1<-0;
    habilitanmat2<-0;
    ganaronmat1<-0;
    ganaronmat2<-0;
    ganarontodas<-0;
    habilitantodas<-0;

    Para i<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
        Para j<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
            Escribir 'Ingrese valor para la fila ',i,', y para la columna ',j,':';
            Leer mt[i,j]
            //escribir mt[i,j]
            //aa<-mt[i,j]
            //Escribir j;
            Si mt[i,j] >= 3 Entonces
                sumaganadores<-sumaganadores + mt[i,j]
                contadorganaron<-contadorganaron + 1;
                promedio<-sumaganadores / contadorganaron;
            Fin Si
        Fin Para
    Fin Para

    Escribir ("");
    // MOSTRAR VALORES DE CADA CELDA
    Para i<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
        Para j<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
            Escribir Sin Saltar mt[i,j], " ";            
        FinPara
        Escribir " "
    FinPara

    //RECORRER LOS VALORES DE LAS COLUMNAS
    Para x<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
        sumacolumnas <- 0
        Para yy<-1 Hasta 2 Hacer
            vlrcolum1 <- mt[yy,x];
            Si yy = 1 Entonces
                Si mt[yy,x] <= 2.9 Entonces
                    habilitanmat1 <- habilitanmat1 + 1;
                SiNo
                    ganaronmat1 <- ganaronmat1 + 1;
                FinSi
                //Escribir ("Los valores de la columna "), x, " son: ", vlrcolum1, " ", vlrcolum2;
            Sino
                Si mt[yy,x] <= 2.9 Entonces
                    habilitanmat2 <- habilitanmat2 + 1;
                SiNo
                    ganaronmat2 <- ganaronmat2 + 1;
                FinSi
            Fin Si

            Si ganaronmat1 = ganaronmat2  Entonces
                ganarontodas <- ganaronmat1;
            Fin Si

            //Escribir ("ff"), x,  yy;
        Fin Para

        //Escribir ("ff"), x,yy;
    Fin Para

    Escribir ("");
    //Escribir sumaganadores;
    Escribir ("La nota promedio de los estudiantes que ganarón es de: "), promedio;
    Escribir ("La cantidad de estudiantes que deben habilitar la materia 1 es de: "), habilitanmat1;
    Escribir ("La cantidad de estudiantes que deben habilitar la materia 2 es de: "), habilitanmat2;
    Escribir ("La cantidad de estudiantes que deben habilitar las 2 materias es de: "), habilitantodas;
    //Escribir  habilitantodas,ganarontodas;

FinAlgoritmo
```

Comment: que has intentado? cual es el problema?publica codigo.

Comment: ¿Qué perfil usas? Tu código me da un error que parece provenir de mi perfil